# wordpress breadcrumb - home > blog > post

Tags: wordpress, breadcrumbs

I would be very thankful for any suggestions about my breadcrumb. 2 days of headaches and I just can't figure it out.

I have a static page for blog entries and I would like to include the url in the breadcrumb.

mysite.com  > blog  > post

Right now I have " mysite.com > post"

Worst case scenario remove home url and to change for blog url, so this breadcrumb displays at least the blog url.

Blog > post

Following code works great but it doesn't display "blog url" as it only calls "home", but I would like to include an echo or something to display the static page called blog after home (home - blog - post ).

Would it be possible to include a link to a page for instance like echo 'Blog< /a>' ? Or even remove home and place before breadcrumb as < a href=/> My Site < /a> >> < a href =/blog> My Blog < /a> >> then rest of breadcrumb ( post / category ).

My goal...
mysite.com  > blog  > post

Thanks !

```
function my_breadcrumb() {
$sep = ' &rsaquo; ';
if (!is_front_page()) {

// Start the breadcrumb with a link to your homepage
    echo '<div class="x"><nav class="x">';
    echo '<a href="';
    echo get_option('home');
    echo '">';
    bloginfo('name');
    echo '</a>' . $sep;

// Check if the current page is a category, an archive or a single page. If so show the category or archive name.
    if (is_category() || is_single() ){
        the_category('title_li=');
    } elseif (is_archive() || is_single()){
        if ( is_day() ) {
            printf( __( '%s', 'text_domain' ), get_the_date() );
        } elseif ( is_month() ) {
            printf( __( '%s', 'text_domain' ), get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'text_domain' ) ) );
        } elseif ( is_year() ) {
            printf( __( '%s', 'text_domain' ), get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'text_domain' ) ) );
        } else {
            _e( 'Blog Archives', 'text_domain' );
        }
    }   
// If the current page is a single post, show its title with the separator
    if (is_single()) {
        echo $sep;
        the_title();
    }   
// If the current page is a static page, show its title.
    if (is_page()) {
        echo the_title();
    }
// if you have a static page assigned to be you posts list page. It will find    the title of the static page and display it. i.e Home >> Blog
    if (is_home()){
        global $post;
                    $page_for_posts_id = get_option('page_for_posts');
                    if ( $page_for_posts_id ) { 
                        $post = get_page($page_for_posts_id);
                        setup_postdata($post);
                        the_title();
                        rewind_posts();
                    }
                }
      echo '</nav></div>';
   }
```

}

//

- note. I am curious as why the posts page isn't showing as code says it should as Home >> Blog. ( I created a page called blog, and then settings - reading - posts page and using home.php as template ). (Front page is using a page called welcome, then settings - reading- front page, template is front-page.php ). 
  ** I am making my own theme and I wouldn't like to add more plugins.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Display Breadcrumb for expected url like : mysite.com > blog > post

```
function my_breadcrumb() {
    $sep = ' > ';
    if (!is_front_page()) {

    // Start the breadcrumb with a link to your homepage
        echo '<div class="breadcrumbs">';
        echo '<a href="';
        echo get_option('home');
        echo '">';
        bloginfo('name');
        echo '</a>' . $sep;

    // Check if the current page is a category, an archive or a single page. If so show the category or archive name.
        if (is_category() || is_single() ){
           echo '<a href="'.get_site_url().'/blog">Blog</a>';
        } elseif (is_archive() || is_single()){
            if ( is_day() ) {
                printf( __( '%s', 'text_domain' ), get_the_date() );
            } elseif ( is_month() ) {
                printf( __( '%s', 'text_domain' ), get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'text_domain' ) ) );
            } elseif ( is_year() ) {
                printf( __( '%s', 'text_domain' ), get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'text_domain' ) ) );
            } else {
                _e( 'Blog Archives', 'text_domain' );
            }
        }

    // If the current page is a single post, show its title with the separator
        if (is_single()) {
            echo $sep;
            the_title();
        }

    // If the current page is a static page, show its title.
        if (is_page()) {
            echo the_title();
        }

    // if you have a static page assigned to be you posts list page. It will find the title of the static page and display it. i.e Home >> Blog
        if (is_home()){
            global $post;
            $page_for_posts_id = get_option('page_for_posts');
            if ( $page_for_posts_id ) { 
                $post = get_page($page_for_posts_id);
                setup_postdata($post);
                the_title();
                rewind_posts();
            }
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: PPL, thank you for your suggestion. It works, thanks !

Comment: @JPDesign: You should accept and  upvote my answer if it works for you.